# MinGW/GCC GLFW linker issue - undefined reference to "glfwInit"

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, glfw, undefined-reference

**TL;DR - I have tried all solutions I could find, nothing has worked so far.**

Hello, I have searched far and wide but I cannot find an answer to my problem.  When I try to compile my C program with GCC, I get an undefined reference to `glfwInit()`.  First, I tried putting the glfw .dll in the same location as the program, which did seemingly nothing.  After this I tried removing the glfw libraries from MinGW's "lib" directory and replacing them with the .dll, and adding `#define GLFW_DLL` to the top of my .c file (same error).  I also tried changing the linking order around, adding -lopengl32 and -lgdi32, renaming one of the static libraries just in case the compiler was confused, etc.  Nothing seems to be working here, but I have previously installed and developed with SDL2 in the same fashion.

**main.c:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<GLFW/glfw3.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    if(!glfwInit()) {
        printf("Failed!");
        return -1;
    }
    printf("Success!");
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

**Instructions to the compiler:**

```
gcc -std=c99 -o project.exe main.c -lglfw3 -lglfw3dll
```

Comment: Have you tried adding -L.

Comment: Yes, one of the things I tried was adding -L and specifying the directory of the libraries.  Unfortunately, same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, I have finally solved the problem.  I followed the instructions in this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bIK95aWk-Bo.  The gist of the video is that you need to download CMake as well as the GLFW version found here: https://www.glfw.org/

Then, you need to hit "Configure" after setting the source and build paths.  After this, hit "Generate."  Then, you need to open a command prompt and locate the newly created MakeFile.  I am using Windows, which means I needed to use the command `mingw32-make`.  The library files then built successfully!

After doing this, I put the created .dll and .a files in the MinGW "lib" folder.  Then, I copied the .dll and placed it in the same directory as my executable.